# Regex to split text within parentheses at end of line using Java

Tags: regex, parentheses

I need to parse some text that has data enclosed within parentheses at the end of line.

```
Snarky Spark was at the stage with his team (Jerry Mander/Kodi Player/Bella Bella)
```

I need to extract the text within parantheses and separated by `forward slash` in capture groups.

1. `Jerry Mander`
2. `Kodi Player`
3. `Bella Bella`

I have tried the following to split by `/`

```
(?:[^\/])+
```

But not able to split it within parenthesis or as end of line criteria.

Appreciate help

Comment: What language/flavor and how are you applying the regex?

Comment: Would this work? [`[^\/(]+(?=[^()]*\)$)`](https://regex101.com/r/vgfph2/2)

Comment: @trincot it seemingly works, but it appears to be too slow. Good use of positive look ahead, but its slow in terms of its speed.

Comment: Then you would need to make use of the language capabilities you are working with. Which language?

Comment: @anubhava updated question with language

Comment: @trincot Java 8+

Comment: @MadPhysicist the language is Java and extraction of the values in within parenthesis is half of the main goal. there is additional processing being done after the `/` split names are extracted

Comment: As per @trincot [his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658050/regex-to-split-text-within-parentheses-at-end-of-line-using-java?noredirect=1#comment96107711_54658050) works and provides the extraction of values

Comment: @RegMem That regex will still find match even if there is no opening `(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with `\G`:

```
(?:\(|(?!^)\G/)([^/)]+)(?=[^()]*\))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1NqMSo/2)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Comment: but the converse problem is with the above approach, if the last parenthesis is missing, it still parses the values correctly, this extraction has to take place if and only if the text has `( blah blah/Blaha Blaha)` at the end of the line